# How do I create a shallow copy of an object so that it may be serialize and sent via a web method call?

Tags: asp.net, xml, serialization

I would like to serialize the properties of the HttpBrowserCapibilities object so that it may be returned via a web method call.  Currently the object cannot be serialized:

```
Cannot serialize member System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase.Capabilities of type System.Collections.IDictionary, because it implements IDictionary.
```

...which is understandable. However, I would like to simply copy out the properties and their values to a hierarchy, i.e.

```
<HttpBrowserCapabilities>
   <IsMobile>true</IsMobile>
</HttpBrowserCapabilities>
```

I'm starting to think I would need to use reflection to copy this object, but I haven't reached a conclusion.  Does anyone have any suggestions to keep this simple?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I posted an answer using `XmlDocument`, but I glossed over some of the web method stuff and didn't realize you were really trying to map a DTO.

Reflection sounds complicated but it really isn't.  The following snippet will do what you want:

```
public static void Populate(object dest, IDictionary dictionary)
{
    Type t = dest.GetType();
    foreach (object key in dictionary)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty(key.ToString(),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if ((prop != null) && prop.CanWrite)
        {
            object value = dictionary[key];
            prop.SetValue(dest, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then invoke this as:

```
BrowserCapsDto dto = new BrowserCapsDto();
Populate(dto, Capabilities);  // Capabilities is the real BrowserCaps
```

It's pretty easy because you already have an `IDictionary` and thus you already know all of the possible names you can map; you don't actually need to use any reflection on the source, just the destination.